# How to add lookup service to local DBpedia Mirror

Tags: lookup, dbpedia

I have made a local DBpedia mirror. It is working fine. Now I want to make a local mirror of **DBpedia Lookup webservice** which will work on my local set up. My actual purpose is to make a clone of DBpedia lookup service in my local set up, so that when i will add some of my own data to local DBpedia graph,the response of the service can be effected automatically.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: This question is far too broad for SO. Also, it is not clear what you mean by the "DBpedia Lookup webservice" you want to mirror/mimic/reimplement. Probably the best place for you to start is the [DBpedia Discussion mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/dbpedia-discussion).

Comment: Were you able to achieve this?. I was also looking for something similar.

Comment: No, I can't achieve this till now. If I can, will share it here.